# "While not in" error - python

Tags: python, loops, variables, while-loop

In this example, we'll set `PH[0]` to `'Ten of Hearts'`, and `guess` to `'Ten'`

The list 'PH' represents a Player's Hand in a card game of Go Fish. When the user guesses a card, they have to guess a card that corresponds with a card in their hand. I wrote this block of code so that if the user inputs an invalid guess (if the guess is not in `PH`, they will be prompted again to enter a new guess)

I feel like I am having problems with the variables in the array `[guess1, guess2, guess3, guess4]`, but I am not too sure.

When the code is executed, the loop goes on forever. I need to be able to get out of the loop in order to return the guess so it can be entered into the next function.

If someone could please help me solve the problem I'm having.

```
guess = str(raw_input("Make a guess : "))

guess11 = guess, 'of Hearts'
guess1 = " ".join(guess11)

guess22 = guess, 'of Diamonds'
guess2 = " ".join(guess22)

guess33 = guess, 'of Clubs'
guess3 = " ".join(guess33)

guess44 = guess, 'of Spades'
guess4 = " ".join(guess44)

while PH[0] not in [guess1, guess2, guess3, guess4] :
    print "You do not have a card like that in your hand."
    guess = str(raw_input("Make another guess : "))

    guess11 = guess, 'of Hearts'
    guess1 = " ".join(guess11)

    guess22 = guess, 'of Diamonds'
    guess2 = " ".join(guess22)

    guess33 = guess, 'of Clubs'
    guess3 = " ".join(guess33)

    guess44 = guess, 'of Spades'
    guess4 = " ".join(guess44)

return guess
```

Comment: That code hurts my eyes! Learn about writing [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) code. It will make your life so much easier.

Comment: It works for me when I set `PH[0]` to `'Ten of Hearts'` and `guess` to `'Ten'`. The loop exits correctly.

Comment: `raw_input` is already a string

Comment: @Basic I will for sure look into that and learn how to make my code better. I am just beginning and learning. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only testing if the *first card* in the players hand is any of he guesses. You need to test each card in the hand:

```
while not any(guess in PH for guess in [guess1, guess2, guess3, guess4]):
```

This takes each guessed card and tests that card against the hand in turn. `any()` stops looping over the guesses when a match is found.

A better idea still is to use set intersections:

```
guesses = {guess1, guess2, guess3, guess4}
while not guesses.intersection(PH):
    # ask for new guesses
```

You want to avoid having to type out your 'ask for a guess' code twice; start a loop with `while True` and use `break` to end the loop when a correct guess has been made:

```
suits = ('Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Clubs', 'Spades')

while True:
    guess = raw_input("Make a guess:")
    guesses = {'{} of {}'.format(guess, suit) for suit in suits}
    if guesses.intersection(PH):
        # correct guess!
        break
    print "You do not have a card like that in your hand."
```

I used a set comprehension to build the guesses in a loop.

Comment: @EvanCooper: but your `while` loop doesn't end until there is a matching card in `PH[0]`. Those other parts will never be reached.